# Using curl with Gitlab job gives invalid yaml error

Tags: curl, gitlab, jobs

So I have the following curl command to hit an Endpoint, but get a `:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep` error.

This is my curl command:

```
 script:
    - curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://main-demo-services.nr.dflop-swf-prod.bee.ds.local/services/dataUser/namebreak/recache/status/'
```

Comment: I do not think this is about the `curl` command. It is a bit hard to see but could it be that the indention is off by one space? Yaml is very restrictive. Usually I would expect the dash to be either intended under the `s` (2 spaces) under `r` (4 spaces).